# How many schools of Tantra are there?

Tags: tantra

Is Tantra related to Shakta sects or Shaiva sects? How many Tantra schools are there in total?

Comment: related to both, as well as others. asking how many is asking for opinions.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda let us know if one is asking how many schools are there is opinion based. Based on scriptures only we will be giving number of schools. Please put an end to this kind of attitude on site. This has been  repetitive from you last 2 years

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Can you please give me a list of all the Shaiva Tantra schools and Shakta Tantra schools. Also a few introductory books would be great.

Comment: Bamachara (Left-hand Tantrism) Tantra is one school that I know.